# Why is it looking for String?

Tags: scala

Given the following code:

```
abstract class Field {
  type T
  val data: List[T]
  def sum: T = data(0) + data(1)
}
```

I get an error on the last line - `def sum: T = data(0) + data(1)`:

> types2.scala:6: error: type mismatch;
>
> found   : Field.this.T
>
> required: String
>
> def sum: T = data(0) + data(1)
>
> ```
>                      ^
> ```

That is, it expects data(1) to be a `String`.
I dont understand why... (scala 2.8.1)

Your explanation will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since `T` does not support an addition operation, compiler assumes `+` to be a string concatenation operation. The following line I tried out at REPL indicates so:

```
scala> implicitly[Any => {def +(s: String): String}]
res16: (Any) => AnyRef{def +(s: String): String} = <function1>
```

What you can do is require that `T`  have a [`Semigroup`](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/Semigroup.scala.html) algebra defined. (A type is a semigroup if it supports an associative append operation.)

```
scala> import scalaz._
import scalaz._

scala> import Scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> abstract class Field[A : Semigroup] {
     |   val data: IndexedSeq[A]
     |   def sum: A = data(0) |+| data(1)
     | }
defined class Field

scala> val f = new Field[Int] {
     |   val data = IndexedSeq(2, 3, 4)
     | }
f: Field[Int] = $anon$1@d1fd51

scala> f.sum
res12: Int = 5
```

I replaced abstract type by a type parameter simply because I do not know how to put a context bound on an abstract type. I also changed type of data from `List[A]` to `IndexedSeq[A]` because as the name indicates indexed sequences are more suitable for indexed access than lists (which is what you do in your `sum` method). And finally, `|+|` is the semigroup append operation. For numeric types it will perform addition. For sequences, concatenation etc.

Answer (score 4):

As a complement to @missingfactor's answer, while in principle I would very much favor `Semigroup`, there is a trait `Numeric` in the standard library which would do the same. And on collections whose content is `Numeric` (where a "`Numeric` structure" exists for the elements' type), you can simply call `collection.sum` (should you want to sum all the elements rather than the two first ones).

I prefer `Semigroup` for two reasons. First `Numeric` is much more than what is needed here, second, what are the exact properties of a `Numeric` structure is not clear. On the other hand, even someone not familiar with basic algebra will have a reasonable understanding of what Numeric means.

So if you are afraid of scalaz and/or semigroups, you can replace `Semigroup` with `Numeric` and `|+|` with `+`. You must `import Numeric.Implicits._` so that `+` is available.

Comment: I changed my answer to use `Semigroup` instead of `Monoid` as associative append operation is all that is needed here.

Comment: Ok, I change my answer to Semigroup too, that will be less confusing.

Comment: +1, looks good now. If OP doesn't want to pull in Scalaz, `Numeric` perhaps is the best solution he can go for.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't know how to invoke `+` in your type `T`, because it knows nothing about `T`. The only solution to compile this `+` is then a pimped string concatenation (by means of the implicit `Predef.any2stringadd`), which expects a string as second argument — hence the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of playing with this, I came up with a very simple solution.
Here is the full program

```
package manytypes

abstract class Field {
  type T
  val data: List[T]
  def add (a: T, b: T): T
}

abstract class FieldInt extends Field {
  type T = Int
  def add (a: T, b: T): T = a + b
}

abstract class FieldDouble extends Field {
  type T = Double
  def add (a: T, b: T): T = a + b
}

abstract class FieldString extends Field {
  type T = String
  def add (a: T, b: T): T = a + b
}

object A extends App {

  val ints: Field = new FieldInt { val data = List(1, 2, 3)}
  val doubles: Field = new FieldDouble { val data = List(1.2, 2.3, 3.4) }
  val strings: Field = new FieldString { val data = List("hello ", "this is ", "a list ")}

  val fields: List[Field] = List(ints, doubles, strings)

  for (field <- fields) println(field.data.reduceLeft(field.add(_, _)))
}
```